# Checking user processor architecture with JS or PHP

Tags: php, javascript, architecture, bit

I want to check the useragent processor architecture either using PHP or JavaScript and then redirect the user to a domain according to the architecture they're using.

E.G.

```
if($Bits32){ //redirect to somewhere
} elseif($Bits64){ //redirect to somewhere
}
```

I tried using the following code but it didn't work correctly:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("WOW64") != -1 || 
    navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Win64") != -1 ){
   document.write("This is a 64 bit OS"); // 64 bit action 
} else {
    document.write("<br><br>");
   document.write("32 bit OS"); //32bit action
}
```

Comment: Remember that mac and linux OS's also have 32 and 64 bit versions. And of course that useragents can lie. I'm not sure how reliable any method of this sort can be.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Can't detect it as scripts runs on server-side. You can try with userAgent as you are trying now, but you have to remember that not everybody uses default full information, so there will always be examples of people on whom it doesn't work.

This could be helpful though it wont solve it completly.
http://blog.endflow.net/?p=285

tl;dr - look for more thatn WOW64 and Win64 ;) also as you can see different apss gives different UserAgents so like i told you - won't work for all.